# Positioning Flex/AIR Desktop App Window to the bottom right corner

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, air

Any clues how this can be achieved? It needs to work on all resolutions .. is there any parent/stage object available to find out the resolution of the system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public function init():void
{
    nativeWindow.x = ( Screen.mainScreen.bounds.width - 300 ) 
    nativeWindow.y = ( Screen.mainScreen.bounds.height - 65 )               
}
```

This is a 300x65 window positioned in the bottom right. You are looking for [Screen](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/display/Screen.html).

Answer (score 3):

Screen.mainScreen.visibleBounds takes the taskbar into account

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to create a transparent window, then maximise it, then position your window inside the transparent one, using standard bottom=0 right=0 properties.

The advantage is that maximise will take into account the windows task bar height, which could change depending on the users set up.

The disadvantage, is that the transparent window will look really ugly on systems that don't support transparency (some Linux builds).

I am also not sure how this works on OSX, you could integrate with Growl, or if on OSX do the window in a different way (DIY Growl).

Comment: Make sense. Any idea which are the Linux builds that would not support transparent windows?

Also.. any other ways to avoid the taskbar height issue.

Answer (score 1):

To position to the center:

```
        nativeWindow.x = ( Screen.mainScreen.bounds.width / 2 - nativeWindow.width / 2);
        nativeWindow.y = ( Screen.mainScreen.bounds.height / 2 - nativeWindow.height / 2);
```